# ef form app c# code first with sqlite error db.SaveChanges no such a table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, ef-code-first

I have a ef form application on vs. I try to add some products on the product table.
When ı am starting the project, shop.db is generating file and ı can see the tables(product and category) but when ı try to add any product to product table, ı am taking "SqliteException: SQLite Error 1: 'no such table: ProductModels'." error.

'SaveChanges (db);' causes the error.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging; 

public class ShopContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<ProductModel> ProductModels { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CategoryModel> CategorieModels { get; set; }


        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder

                .UseSqlite("Data Source=shop.db");

        }
    }
    public class ProductModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public decimal Price { get; set; }

    }

    public class CategoryModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    public class Class1
    {
        public void AddProduct()
        {
            using (var db = new ShopContext())
            {
                var p = new ProductModel();

                p.Name = "Samsung s6";
                p.Price = 100000;

                db.ProductModels.Add(p);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

    }
```

I have a form. It contains a button and a text.When I click the button, I want the product to be added to the database and text to be written.Forms code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace WindowsFormsApp4
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
        }

        public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Class1 c = new Class1();
            c.AddProduct();
            label1.Text = "Yazı";

        }
    }
}
```

How to solve it?

Comment: Did you run the 'update-database' command after generating migrations? Also, have you actually verified that the desired tables exist in the database, using sqllite client or something?

Comment: Yes,ı did. I see these tables on sqlite browser.

Answer (score 0):

Unless otherwise specified, EF is looking for a table named `ProductModel` which doesn't exist.

You can either rename your DbSet to:     (I would recommend this)

```
  public DbSet<ProductModel> Product { get; set; }
  public DbSet<CategoryModel> Category { get; set; }
```

OR you can explicitly set the table name in the model:

```
[Table("Product")]
public class ProductModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Didn't the questioner already implement these?

Comment: I tried all of these but ı still take the same error.